# Drag-and-Drop UWP vs Button Style

Tags: xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have a question that is me to leave upset. I want to drag and drop an item in a listview and I can not do when I have a style applied to my item. Only I can do and is working perfectly when I have no style (MyButtonStyle) applied / or do not have this image in style. When I have style (MyButtonStyle), ItemDragStarting event is not called.

Another situation: I have tapped associated event, and when I apply this style crashes. I do not understand what the problem is, can someone help me?

Thank you:

**Code MainPage:**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _ObservableCollection}" Style="{StaticResource MyListViewStyle}" SelectionMode="None" CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="MyListView_OnDragItemsStarting">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Tapped="Item_Tapped" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

**XAML Style code:**

```
 <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyColor1}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonContent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent" To="{StaticResource MyColor2}" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ButtonContent"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent" To="{StaticResource MyColor3}" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Image Width="200" Height="200">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding MyImage, Mode=OneTime}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you would be to not use a `Button` at all. Use `IsItemClickEnabled` property and `ItemClick` event on the `ListView` instead, then put your image in the `ItemContainerStyle`. It will fix your drag and drop issues, focus problems and result in better performance.

Comment: Hi @Filip Skakun, thanks for your reply. 
It's very hard do apply this style in ItemContainerStyle or I dont understand what I do for work.