# UWP ListviewItem Customize Pointer Events preserving Drag & Drop functionality

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, listviewitem, itemtemplate

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794887/drag-and-drop-uwp-vs-button-style), I'm with the same and other doubts.

Like the user @fipcurren88 I were using Buttons inside ListView ItemTemplate to customize the behavior of pointer events (Pointer Over and Pressed). This is the way I usually do it until I found Drag and Drop didn't work and using a Button inside a ItemTemplate is the wrong approach (like @Filip Skakun mentioned in the same question).

Removing the custom Button and using Itemtemplate directly with the content I want (an Image for example - the custom Button content) I didn't knew how to set the background colors for other states (pointer over and pressed for example). I found out the solution using ListViewItemPresenter in the ItemContainerStyle were I can set different backgrounds to each Pointer Event.

But, I lost the PointerDownThemeAnimation on the Item and I don't know how to get it back. Using a Button is easy, but it affects the Drag and Drop functionality.

This is the **Problem Number 1**.

This works with simple Items (a single Image), but imagine I have a more complex Item (a Image, a Grid and a TextBlock inside the Grid). I want to change the Grid Background (or the Textblock Foreground) while Pointer is over and/or while the pressed event.

In this case I know the ListViewItemPresenter solution will not work. I need a more specific way to define the different states (VisualStateManager, Common States). Using a custom Button will affect the Drag and Drop functionality (the starting point of the other thread).

What can I do?!

Let's call this **Problem Number 2**.

Any UWP/XAML Expert that can clear me mind? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These requests can all be done in the xaml code by modifying the [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx), and doing this will not affect the Drag and Drop function of `ListView`.

For your both questions, you can copy the style of `x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded"` into your `Page.Resource` and remove the `x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded"`, so will this style be applied to all the `ListViewItem`s in your page.

If you have `Grid`, `Image`, and `TextBlock` together in an item, you can set `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Column="0"
                        Source="{Binding image}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding txt}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then if you want to change the background of the item and the the foreground of your text when your item is in `PointerOver` or `Pressed` state, you just need to find this two `VisualState`s in the style and for example modify them like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

By doing this, the `Background` targets the background of the whole item, not just the `Grid`. The `Grid` will adapt to the controls inside it even you set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to the `Grid` by default, this is because by default it uses `ContentPresent` like this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
```

If you change the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties in the style to `Stretch`, your `Grid` in the `DateTemplate` will fill the whole item. In this scenario, changing the `Background` of `BorderBackground` and the `Foreground` of `ContentPresenter` in the visual state can still work.